# Existe alguma expressão que permita distinguir entre "nós" inclusivo e exclusivo?

Tags: pronomes

Em línguas com o conceito de [inclusividade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusividade_(lingu%C3%ADstica)), existe uma forma que permite distinguir entre o uso de forma exclusiva ou inclusiva do pronome *nós*. A forma exclusiva inclui o orador no sujeito da oração, *mas não o interlocutor*; a forma inclusiva *inclui o interlocutor*.

Por exemplo:

- *(Nós) ganhamos a lotaria, **mas tu não***.  (Forma *exclusiva*)
- *(Nós) ganhamos a lotaria, **e tu também***. (Forma *inclusiva*)

---

Existe alguma expressão que permita distinguir as duas formas, numa maneira que não dependa no contexto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que em português não haja distinção entre o "nós" inclusivo e o "nós" exclusivo.

> - Aonde (nós) vamos hoje à noite?
> - Vocês eu não sei, mas nós vamos a um bar.

O diálogo acima pode ocorrer entre um grupo de amigos. O primeiro "nós" inclui o(s) interlocutor(es), enquanto o segundo não.

Entretanto é possível em português marcar a inclusividade:

> - Aonde (nós) vamos hoje à noite?
> - Vocês eu não sei, mas nós vamos a um bar.
> - Que pena. Achei que sairíamos nós **todos**.

*Nota: desconheço a colocação "nós outros" no português brasileiro e entendo que "nós" e "a gente" sejam perfeitamente intercambiáveis sem distinção semântica (de sentido).*

Answer (score 3):

Existem, de facto, formas de distinguir entre as várias formas:

- *Nós* - usado de forma inclusiva (Eu, tu e outros)
- *Nós outros / a gente* - usado de forma exclusiva (Eu e os outros, mas tu não)

Embora *nós outros* seja (muito) raro (principalmente quando comparado com o equivalente castelhano *nosotros*), esta forma é correta; já *a gente* parece ser bastante comum no Brasil. O facto de estas expressões serem relativamente raras pode tornar mais fácil *não* as utilizar, já que é possível que algumas pessoas não percebam o seu significado.

---

<sup>Fonte:
[https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusividade_(linguística)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusividade_(lingu%C3%ADstica))</sup>

Comment: "A gente" pode sim incluir "você".

Comment: Definitivamente: «Mas a gente ainda ontem a viu, e tu já não te lembras!?» E *gente* não é nada raro, nem mesmo em Portugal.

Comment: @Jacinto A Wikipedia discorda. E cita várias fontes. Será que está errada? Tem alguma fonte que diga o contrário?

Comment: Tenho: «**a gente** Locução que corresponde semanticamente ao pronome pessoal *nós*» [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gente). Repara que diz que é semanticamente equivalente a *nós*, sem excluir o interlocutor. Encontras o mesmo nos outros dicionários online e também no Houaiss e no dicionário da Academia. Não é o primeiro erro que encontro na wikipédia.